# Button vs link vs input type="submit" on a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, hyperlink

A user logs in to his control panel and sees his incoming messages. Near each message there is a "Reply" button. What is the correct way to implement that button?

I see three main options:

1. **Use a link:**

   ```
   <a href="customer.php?reply&messageid=1234">Reply</a>.
   ```

   Disadvantage:

   - We need to style that link to look like a button. Because I think that action "Reply" should be represented by a button, not a link (in my opinion links should be used when they link to some resource and when we have a noun in link text; and if we want to make an action and have a verb (action) in a caption - button should be used).

2. **Use a button:**

   ```
   <button onclick="location.href='customer.php?reply&messageid=1234'">Reply</button>`
   ```

   Disadvantage:

   - The user must have JavaScript enabled. Though based on our statistics 99.8% of our users have JavaScript enabled, and if they don't it will be really difficult for them to work on our website anyway (we have many features implemented with JavaScript). So I think that 100% of our actual active users have JavaScript enabled.

3. **Use a form with `<input type="submit">`:**

   ```
   <form action="customer.php?reply" method="get">
     <input name="messageid" type="hidden" value="1234" />
     <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
   </form>
   ```

   Disadvantage:

   - I think using form here is "artificial". A user doesn't enter anything. We use the form just to make our button work. I also think that using POST request when we don't change anything and just need to show a reply form to a user - violates REST principles. But even with using GET I still think that using form is artificial in this case.

Some other notes:

- Using a button inside a link doesn't work in IE.
- It's a private section of our website so search engines can't see it and we don't really need a link to help search engine follow it and index the resource (it's a usual argument for using links in web instead of buttons)

Which one would you choose and why?

**UPD.** Well, I have decided to use a link. Thank you everyone for discussion!

Comment: `<button>`s submit a form too, if you want something more stylable than `<input type="button">`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would definitely use a link: **progressive enhancement**.

You want the button to be usable even with Javascript turned off (remember: every user is a non-javascript-user for the duration of the page load. If they're on a slow connection (e.g. mobile), they should be able to reply as soon as they see the button).

Styling is a non issue (you weren't gonna use the default button styles, were you?).

Using POST when the user isn't submitting anything sure is wrong. Even with GET, it's still not really form material...

Comment: I've heard the argument that one should not style form controls and buttons, but leave it to the browser and OS for consistency so users feel familiar with the UI. I personally think that's a bit hardcore.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I couldn't disagree more. Buttons and form controls should feel native to your application, not the OS (unless you're building a native app). Obviously, don't go overboard; be sure that you don't throw off your users by some fancy-pants controls. Keep the spirit of the buttons/controls, but tweak it to fit your overall theme.

Comment: I was gonna use the default button style :) What is wrong with that?

Comment: @nightcoder - Regardless, the point still stands. Styling the link is not the issue. 5-10 lines of CSS will do the trick. What you should really care about is the semantics.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Absolutely. I recall someone on SO trying to figure out how use alternating-colored text-shadows with some crazy serif Google font in a text input with no borders or background. Some people get carried away and it can get confusing to the user, but the default button styles sure are *ugly*.

Comment: @JosephSilber, but don't you think that based on the semantics button would fit better here? Because the semantics here say that we have an action, and buttons should be used for actions.

Comment: @nightcoder: It links to a page with the reply form, not sends the actual reply... correct?

Comment: @WesleyMurch, I see your point. What if later I decide to open reply form in a popup modal window? Would semantics say that button should be used in that case?

Comment: @JosephSilber - a link with an href also issues a `GET` request. What makes it a form submission is the presence of querystring values. Since nightcoder's links have querystring values, a form submission is implied. Using a link spoofs the form submission.  And, of course, that's totally acceptable - I prefer to use a link myself because it's easier to style. But semantically, I definitely see nightcoder's point. I'd say it doesn't matter much, but a `<form method="get">` is sematically more correct - at least a little bit - because of the querystring values.

Comment: @nightcoder No, it's still the same thing - you aren't performing an action or reading user input, you're linking to a URL. I guess there's an argument for a `<form method="get">` but in this case I don't think it makes sense. What if you change your URLs to use segments instead of query strings? Then there'd be no question, right?

Comment: As a side note, I really don't see what progressive enhancement has to do with this.

Comment: @JosephSilber, Thank you for an active participation in the discussion!

Comment: Here's one argument on to why you should style your own buttons and input forms. Sure having native buttons would be awesome if only it would work. Input dimensions are different on different OS and won't use the same amount of space. In other words, you could design a form that look great on windows but is completely screwed up on linux or osx. Styling your own input force a consistent behavior across OS and Browsers.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to style `<a>` and `<button>` identically, just use a common class name. `<input type="button">` can be a little trickier, but you don't need to use it.

Your tag choice should *never* be dictated by your intended presentation, but what the element *is* and what it *does*. Links should be marked up as 
`<a>`.

Comment: +1, Thank you for your active participation in the discussion, it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a `POST` is wrong.  So, set your form to use `method="get"`.  Use just one form and leave out the hidden fields.  Using `<button>`, the displayed text can differ from the submitted value.

```
<form action="customer.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="reply" />
    <div class="message">
        <div class="messageBody">..</div>
        <button name="messageid" value="1234">Reply</button>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="messageBody">..</div>
        <button name="messageid" value="1235">Reply</button>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

All methods are correct, except that method 2 is correct only under the assumption that you can safely ignore non-JavaScript browsing.

The assumptions and comments presented about forms are incorrect, or at least misleading. A form need not involve user input; forms can be used e.g. to submit previously collected data, with no other fields but a submit field. And the POST method can be used even when not changing anything, e.g. due to the amount of input data (as there are fairly low upper limits on GET data); besides, the form presented in the question uses GET, the default method.

Otherwise, this is mostly a non-constructive question, calling for discussion and argumentation rather than technical solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One can always use both, like;

```
<button><a href="..">Click Me</a></button>
```